# "low Disk Spac on Filesystem root" ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, filesystem, disk-usage

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           782M  2,7M  779M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   28G   26G   82M 100% /
tmpfs           3,9G  6,1M  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10859
/dev/loop3       60M   60M     0 100% /snap/discord/120
/dev/loop4      126M  126M     0 100% /snap/docker/471
/dev/loop6      132M  132M     0 100% /snap/docker/796
/dev/loop5       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/904
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop8      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10583
/dev/loop10      94M   94M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/118
/dev/loop9       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop11      96M   96M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/123
/dev/loop13     218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop12      11M   11M     0 100% /snap/ncspot/85
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   52M   45M  54% /boot/efi
/dev/loop15      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop14      58M   58M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/97
/dev/loop17     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop16      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop18      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop19      52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop20      11M   11M     0 100% /snap/ncspot/72
/dev/loop21      76M   76M     0 100% /snap/discord/121
/dev/loop22      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
tmpfs           782M   28K  781M   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           782M   36K  781M   1% /run/user/1000
```

the problem:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu, just for work on my projects now, I didn't probably give it enough space in the first place I know that already, however, seems I don't really understand how this works cuz due to pictures under this paragraph there should be space left to operate

I did some digging and found this is about the temp files for some people but I don't see the temp full or anything... maybe I'm just dumb

[image]

since there is not much space I can't really delete much from anywhere

[image] [image]

however I expected some space problems and left 500mb unalocated.

[image]

but I don't know which partion I should expand or what to do at all, cuz there clearly should still be some space left in the device and even if it's not I really don't know where should I add those 500mb since `root` and `Filesystem root` are the same and there still is visible free space...

can anyone pls help? I can't create my virtual environment now, upgrade system or anything else there is always an error

thank you

Comment: Think your best bet will be to get an external USB drive, HD or SSD and install Ubuntu to it.  Trying to move and/or expand your partitions will probably lead to data lost and/or non booting OS.  500MB is almost useless for extra space, need GBs.

Comment: If you have all your data backup and want to try.  From Windows shrink p3 by about 20 or 25 GBs, Move left side of p3 to right same amount.  Move p2 next to left side of p3.   From a Live Ubuntu USB open gparted and add space to p5.  Do Not use Ubuntu to adjust Windows partitions, Use Windows only on Windows.  Windows probably give sissy fit trying to boot.  Check google first before doing.  Data can be lost, back up.

Comment: You might be able to save enough space for the time being with "sudo apt autoremove" and sudo apt clean. The former removes unused packages including old kernels and the latter removes packages from a cache

Comment: thank's guys I'm probably gonna just make a system snap and reinstall both of my OS and make a bigger partition this time, seems there is no other option in this case